# algorithm to count cows in farm ( js or any language)

Tags: javascript, loops, count

i need to count number of cows in farm, starting from this year (2017)  to year at the end (2057), fi in this farm is 1 cow, witch born cows , after 4 years this cows born his own cows so on... every calf can born 1 calf every ear, and no one dies in this farm. How to count number of cows?

Comment: sounds more like a math problem.

Comment: Try doing a few examples yourself on paper. Do one cow, skip ahead 4 years, let the cow give birth, then count the cows. Then skip ahead 4 years and let each cow give birth, and count the cows. Do this a few times and get a sense of the pattern intuitively. Then try to express this pattern mathematically. Test your math function: does it agree with the same number of cows you counted in your own experiments? If so, all that's left is expressing it in a programming language. I promise you that's the easiest part.

Comment: You need a list of cows-ages and a loop `for (year =2017; year <= 2057; ++year) { }`. I leave th e loop body to you...